# loop through div class to obtain a range of values

Tags: c#, html, linq, loops, iteration

I have an html like as you can see below, how can I loop through the elements and grab the value in the strong tag and as well ass the value in the a tag then end the loop at the closing p-tag?
what I am trying to get is: Actor{Brian Keith, Brian K, B Keith}
  `

**Genre:** 
     Adventure , 
                Family, 
                Drama

```
<p>
         <strong>Actor: </strong>
            <a title=" Brian Keith"> Brian Keith</a>, 
            <a title=" Tommy Kirk"> Tommy Kirk</a>, 
            <a title=" Kevin Corcoran "> Kevin Corcoran </a>                    
</p>

<p>
        <strong>Director: </strong>
            <a title="Norman Tokar">Norman Tokar</a>                    
            </p>
```

`

Comment: use javascript/jquery to access the value of the elements

Comment: @MB The question is tagged as c#.

Comment: i want to do it in c#

Comment: you can't access DOM info with c#

Comment: i know i can using Htmlagility pack and linq query. inam learning to programme. i did the research and i can access DOM with regex or Linq. eg. String title = div.Descendants().Where(i => i.Name == "h2").FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know you can use HtmlAgilityPack. So I would do it as:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlstring);

var items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//strong")
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Name = x.InnerText,
                Values = x.SelectNodes("../a").Select(a => a.InnerHtml).ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
```